# Twisted File Location

Tags: command-line, twisted

I'm following this [Twisted tutorial](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/asynchronous.html), and I have a question regarding command line syntax.
With **twistd -n web --path .** I can run the code **AsyncResponse.rpy** by calling **localhost:8080/AsyncResponse.rpy**, so what URL should I use when the command change to **twistd -n web --path /directory/containing/script/.** 

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The URL does not change.  The `--path` option to the `twistd web` plugin says what directory gets exposed at `/`.

Comment: Then it's going to report "No Such Resource" and "File not found.". You can see the screenshot of my page following [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/st1ti1joahc22ib/screenshot.png?dl=0)